# html merge 2 columns in 1 with 100% width bootstrap 2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have the following HTML markup in my .NET MVC project:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6">@Model.Data</div>
    <div class="span6">@Model.OtherData</div>
</div>
```

I'm getting `data` from server. So I want to do the following:
If `data` is empty then show `other data` with `width = 100%`.
Just to clarify I want to do something like that:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">@Model.OtherData</div>
</div>
```

Or vice versa.

Is there a way to do that? Maybe with using different HTML tags / CSS classes.

Comment: Simply add the class `w-100` to your other data ?

Comment: `I'm getting data from server` - How?

Comment: Ok. I see that you're using some server tags. I'm not sure what the technology but surly you can set class names by the condition if `@Model.Data` is exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially you just want conditionally display the `@Model.Data` only if it isn't `null`. You can also set the col class with a variable, and conditionally change that variable depending if `@Model.Data` exists or not. Try something like this:

```html
@ {
    var colClass = 'span6';

    if (@Model.Data == null) {
      colClass = 'span12';
    }
}

<div class="row">
    @if (@Model.Data != null) {
        <div class="@colClass">@Model.Data</div>
    }
    <div class="@colClass">@Model.OtherData</div>
</div>
```